# Firefox - Service worker stopped automatically

Tags: angular, firefox, angular-service-worker

I am running three service workers parallel for different purposes and one of them is angular service worker. In Chrome, Chromium based Microsoft Edge all three workers run fine without stopping until it completes the intended tasks.

However in Firefox, all three service workers stops immediately after they become active. If I manually go and 'start' the service workers from 'Application tool' all works fine.

I would like to know why in Firefox only it auto stops the service workers.